# How to add customize Prime NG components

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, jquery-steps

My project is using Prime NG components. There is one requirement which is not provided by Prime NG as of now in their p-steps component. I want to customize Prime NG p-steps component. Is there any way to create one new component under Prime NG component, which i can use as p-custom-steps as selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can.
In case that you just need to modify styles of a PrimeNG component you could override the css sleectors that each component provides. In case that you have to change the functionality you can use inheritance to modify the component to add your custom functions and stuff.

Take a look to this post, it surely will clear your mind https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2

Comment: Though this question I asked long back, would like to say thanks to you. I was able to customize the prime-ng component after seeing your answer :)